# Spring, Hibernate, MVC Error(s)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am creating a web application (MVC) using Spring, Hibernate, and I receive the error when I run it on server (Glassfish v4.1 is used). Below is the error:

> cannot Deploy project1
>   deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource1' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource1' is defined. Please see server.log for more details.

How can I fix the this error? Thanks in advance.

This is 'applicationContext.xml' file:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuzHR.jpg

This is 'persistence.xml' file:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LLAH.jpg

Comment: The error seems quite clear... `No bean named 'dataSource1' is defined.` You are referencing a datasource that doesn't exist.

Comment: I have added 2 files of 'applicationContent.xml' & 'persistence.xml'. Where can I go to fix the error? Thanks. Sorry, I am a beginner.

Comment: Add it as content to your post, not as links. But read the stacktrace and figure out which bean you need to reference. I suspect it is a bean named `dataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

Like @M. Deinum has commented, you need to ensure you have defined a bean with the name "dataSource1" and of type *javax.sql.DataSource* similar to this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">  
    <property name="URL" value="${url}" />  
    <property name="user" value="${username}"/>  
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>   
  </property>  
</bean>
```

Comment: I have added 2 files of 'applicationContent.xml' & 'persistence.xml'. Where can I go to fix the error? Thanks. Sorry, I am a beginner.

Comment: It looks like you just have your bean named incorrectly for how you're referencing it. For bean id="entityManagerFactory" you have p-dataSource-ref="dataSource1" but your datasource bean (first of the applicationContext.xml) has id="datasource". Those need to match.

Comment: I can't comment on your latest question, but it either belongs in an edit for the original question or in a question of its own. The answer though, is that you don't have the class SQLServerDriver included in your classpath through a library JAR. Here is some information on how to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: I added SQL Server driver sqljdbc.jar, sqljdbc4.jar, or sqljdbc41.jar in the 'Libraries' under 'Java Build Path', but I still receive the same error.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Eclipse so this will be harder for me to debug. I'm assuming that you added the JAR as an 'External JAR' and you are running your application with Eclipse. You might want to try running Project > Clean. I'm not sure but you might need to check the box for the JAR under the 'Order and Export' tab in 'Java Build Path'. Finally, you can try adding a 'Classpath Variable' under Preferences > Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables. I believe the format for that should follow from that Microsoft guide I posted in my last comment.